# Delete only .jpg files from folder in android

Tags: android

This is any way to delete only .jpg files from folder?
This is my remove method:

```
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
        }
    }
```

How can I remove only .jpg files from folder?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            String filename = children[i];
            if (filename.endsWith(".jpeg") || filename.endsWith(".jpg"))
                new File(dir, filename).delete();
        }
 }
```

or you prefer the for-each version

```
 if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            String[] children = dir.list();
            for (String child : children) {
                if (child.endsWith(".jpeg") || child.endsWith(".jpeg"))
                    new File(dir, child).delete();
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        String[] children = dir.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
            if(children[i].endsWith('.jpg' || children[i].endsWith('.jpeg'))
            {
                new File(dir, children[i]).delete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 File dir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"MyFolder");
```

Then call

```
walkdir(dir);

public void walkdir(File dir) {
String Patternjpg = ".jpg";

File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();

if (listFile != null) {
for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
walkdir(listFile[i]);
} else {
if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(Patternjpg)){
  //Do what ever u want
   listFile[i].delete();    
}
}
}  
}    
}
```