# How can I create a listView of all TEXT file from my sdcard?

Tags: android

**what I need :**

1) I need to find all TEXT file which is my sdcard folder/sub folder also.

2)After than I store that all file name and path store into the ArrayList.

So, first I have to sort the first point. What classes are  required for this ?

**What I search:**

1)FilenameFilter but not getting proper way to use this

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Comment: but not able to search all the files those having a txt extension

Comment: @AM check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210519/how-to-access-all-mp3-files-from-all-the-subfolders-in-the-sdcard similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will give you a all text files from your sdcard

```
private ArrayList<String> allImages = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] extensions = { "txt" };

    private void loadAllImages(String rootFolder) {

        File file = new File(rootFolder);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    if (f.isDirectory()) {
                        loadAllImages(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                            if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(extensions[i])) {
                                allImages.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: in rootFolder , what I suppose to pass ?like : Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() or something else

Comment: Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() for root folder  or if you want specific folder then like : /mnt/sdcard/yourfolder

Answer (score 1):

Try out below code to get all the text files from sdcard.

> ```
>         private txtFileFilter txtff = new txtFileFilter(); 
>          private void scanAllTxtFiles(File location, ArrayList<String> list) {
>                     File[] files = location.listFiles(txtff);
>                     if (files != null) {
>                         for (File f : files) {
>                             if (f.isDirectory()) {
>                                 scanAllTxtFiles(f, list);
>                             } else if (f.isFile()) {
>                                 list.add(f.getAbsolutePath().substring(
>                                         externalPathLength));
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
>       private class txtFileFilter implements FileFilter {
>                 @Override
>                 public boolean accept(File pathname, String filename) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
>                     if (filename.endsWith(".txt")) {
>                         return true;
>                     } 
>                     return false;
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: It will give you the text files from the current directory.

Comment: To route through subfolder you have to write logic. Check my updated answer.

Comment: externalPathLength ... what is this ?

Comment: Its the extension of file name.