# List of Mp3 files from a specific folder - Android

Tags: android, mp3, directory

How i get list of all Mp3 files from a specific folder?

My folder is

```
 FILE_PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/my folder/"
```

This following code show all mp3 from all Folder .. i want sow mp3 from my folder only

```
 Cursor createCursor(String filter) {
    ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
    String selection;

    if (mShowAll) {
        selection = "(_DATA LIKE ?)";
        args.add("%");
    } else {
        selection = "(";
        for (String extension : CheapSoundFile.getSupportedExtensions()) {
            args.add("%." + extension);
            if (selection.length() > 1) {
                selection += " OR ";
            }
            selection += "(_DATA LIKE ?)";
            selection  = selection  + "AND (IS_MUSIC=1)";
        }
        selection += ")";

        selection = "(" + selection + ") AND (_DATA NOT LIKE ?)";
        args.add("%espeak-data/scratch%");
    }

    if (filter != null && filter.length() > 0) {
        filter = "%" + filter + "%";
        selection =
            "(" + selection + " AND " +
            "((TITLE LIKE ?) OR (ARTIST LIKE ?) OR (ALBUM LIKE ?)))";
        args.add(filter);
        args.add(filter);
        args.add(filter);
    }
```

Comment: Any one? can help me?

Comment: check this  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210519/how-to-access-all-mp3-files-from-all-the-subfolders-in-the-sdcard

Comment: Yes it work but i dont know how to do with my code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is Working fine

```
 Cursor createCursor(String filter) {
    ArrayList<String> args = new ArrayList<String>();
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

    String selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC + " !=" + 0
            + " AND " + MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA + " LIKE '" + path
            + "/Fast Mp3 Downloader/%'";



    if (filter != null && filter.length() > 0) {
        filter = "%" + filter + "%";
        selection =
            "(" + selection + " AND " +
            "((TITLE LIKE ?) OR (ARTIST LIKE ?) OR (ALBUM LIKE ?)))";
        args.add(filter);
        args.add(filter);
        args.add(filter);
    }

    String[] argsArray = args.toArray(new String[args.size()]);

    getExternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray);
    getInternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray);

    Cursor c = new MergeCursor(new Cursor[] {
            getExternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray),
            getInternalAudioCursor(selection, argsArray)});
    startManagingCursor(c);
    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*Use the below code to get the list of mp3 files from the desired folder :-*

```
private ArrayList<String> listmp3 = new ArrayList<String>();
    String[] extensions = { "mp3" };

    private void loadmp3(String YourFolderPath) {

        File file = new File(YourFolderPath);
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            File[] files = file.listFiles();
            if (files != null && files.length > 0) {
                for (File f : files) {
                    if (f.isDirectory()) {
                        loadmp3(f.getAbsolutePath());
                    } else {
                        for (int i = 0; i < extensions.length; i++) {
                            if (f.getAbsolutePath().endsWith(extensions[i])) {
                                listmp3.add(f.getAbsolutePath());
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
```