# List all the files from a specific folder in android

Tags: android, listview

I tried this one : [How to access all mp3 files from all the subfolders in the sdcard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210519/how-to-access-all-mp3-files-from-all-the-subfolders-in-the-sdcard)

I need to list all .amr files from a folder (ABC) and on click of any list item, do something.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain what you tried and what specific problems you encountered.

Comment: I am new to android and tried the codes from the link given. Thanks.

Comment: you can use ACTION_PICK intent with a specific uri to the folder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File f = new File(path);        
File file[] = f.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ file.length);
for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
{
    //here populate your listview 
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
}
```

This will list all the files in the pictures folder. **Use the path to your folder** to get the files in that folder
**Dont forget to use the following permission**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: 'for' loop replaceable with 'foreach.
Reports for loops which iterate over collections or arrays, and can be replaced with the foreach iteration syntax, available in Java 5 and newer.