# Android -Listing mp3 files in listview from internal storage

Tags: android

I've been trying to fetch all mp3 files from internal storage and list them in a listview in my activity. I know there are other related questions like this one, but i am not able to understand.
I need a proper code which fetches the files and also list them. 
Thanks.

**Edit**

```
public class MainScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<String> songslist = new ArrayList<String>();
    ListView songslistview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.song_list);

    @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.main_screen);
             Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
             getallmp3();



         }

    public void getallmp3(){
         File dir=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
         String pattern=".mp3";
         File listfile[]=dir.listFiles();
         if(listfile!=null) {
             for(File file:dir.listFiles()) {
                 if(file.getName().endsWith(pattern)){
                    songslist.add(file.getName());
                 }
             }
             ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,songslist);
            songslistview.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access all mp3 files from all the subfolders in the sdcard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17210519/how-to-access-all-mp3-files-from-all-the-subfolders-in-the-sdcard)

Comment: I would suggest breaking your problem into smaller parts.  1) How to create a listview with "dummy" items.  2) How to access mp3 files from internal storage.  Then how to put 1 and 2 together?  I don't think anyone is going to write the program for you... but I can say that you will probably need a List<Mp3 File Objects>, that is put into an adapter that is associated with a listview.  Then you have to figure out how to add MP3 files to this list.  I would suggest something like checking out the 'slidenerd' youtube channel and look for videos on listviews.

Comment: I edited the question. Can you check for what is wrong with the code? Still a little confused. The application is crashing.

Answer (score 0):

This is My AsyncTask

```
class loadSongs extends AsyncTask<String, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
            super.onPostExecute(hashMaps);
            songList1 = hashMaps;
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... params) {

            listdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());

            return null;
        }

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(String rootPath) {
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();


            try {
                File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
                File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(); //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
                for (File file : files) {
                    if (file.isDirectory()) {
                        if (getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()) != null) {
                            fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {
                        HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                        Log.d("file path", "" + file.getAbsolutePath());
                        song.put("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                        Log.d("file name playlist", "" + file.getName());
                        song.put("file_name", file.getName());
                        fileList.add(song);
                    }
                }
                return fileList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

execute Aysnck in you class

```
 new loadSongs().execute();
```

Here is  Method listdir

```
public void listdir(File dir) {
        String msqPattern = ".mp3";// Can include more strings for more extensions and check it.

        File[] listFile = dir.listFiles();

        if (listFile != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    listdir(listFile[i]);
                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(msqPattern)) {
                        Music_File_Name.add(listFile[i].getName());
                        Music_File_Path.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());

                    }
                }
            }
        }

  }
```

Here is Adapter Class

```
public class DeafaultMusic_Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<String> list, path;
    Context context;
    MediaPlayer mpintro;

    public DeafaultMusic_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> list, ArrayList<String> path) {
        this.context = context;
        this.path = path;
        this.list = list;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.music_list, parent, false);
        TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songTitle);
        TextView album = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.songAlbum);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        title.setText(list.get(position));

        icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Model.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    Model.mediaPlayer.stop();
                    Model.mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse(path.get(position)));
                    Model.mediaPlayer.start();


                }
                else {
                    Model.mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse(path.get(position)));


                    Model.mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }
        });


        return convertView;
    }


}
```

i have used gridview instead of listview like this

```
 DeafaultMusic_Adapter adapter = new DeafaultMusic_Adapter(c, Music_File_Name, Music_File_Path);
        Log.d("music file name", "" + Music_File_Name);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Intent i = new Intent(c, CropMusic.class);
                i.putExtra("musicPath", "" + Music_File_Path.get(position));
                i.putExtra("musicName", "" + Music_File_Name.get(position));
                startActivity(i);
                activity.overridePendingTransition(R.anim.activity_in,R.anim.activity_out);

            }
        });
```

on music click i am passing music path to next acticity and play it to music player

you can play a music from listview like this

```
icon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(Model.mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                {
                    Model.mediaPlayer.stop();
                    Model.mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse(path.get(position)));
                    Model.mediaPlayer.start();


                }
                else {
                    Model.mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(context,Uri.parse(path.get(position)));

//                mpintro.setLooping(true);
                    Model.mediaPlayer.start();
                }

            }
        });
```

here icon is my imageveiw with play icon

in this method i have globally define musicplayer oblject so we can reset it when next music select

```
public class Model
{
 public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

}
```

comment below if any query